# Request elevation for java

Tags: java, windows, elevation

We have to run the updater of our Java-based application using elevation (so it can overwrite files in the install location, usually `%ProgramFiles%\<productName>`). Until now I used a .vbs script that requests elevation and invokes another script. I was told that in some companies .vbs scripts are not allowed to be run because of security reasons. I'd rather should create a .exe that requires elevation. That's what I did, but now when I try to launch directly that elevation-requiring application from Java it fails with an java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation.

How to run this application that Windows automatically requests the required elevation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there seem to be at least two ways of launching something on Windows. In Java one is implemented using `Process`. The other I found in SWT's implementation of `Program.launch` (using `ShellExecute`). When using the latter, Windows asks the user for elevation if necessary.